# CDH Network Interface Speed Suppress

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, centos7, cloudera-cdh

i configured CDH 5.5.2 on myCentOS 7.1. Everything working perfectly except below warnings related to Network

Network Interface Speed Suppress...

The following network interface(s) appear to be operating at less than full speed: virbr0-nic.2 host network interface(s) appear to be operating at full speed.For 1 host network interface(s), the Cloudera Manager Agent could not determine the duplex mode or interface speed.

Anyone help me how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default CDH Hosts are required to be deployed on servers with 1GB or better networking interfaces.
But you can always change the default configurations to meet your server configurations:

1- From Cloudera Manager Navigate to "**Hosts -> All Hosts**" and then click "**Configuration**" in this page.

2- In the search bar, search for "**Network Interface**".

3- Depending on the type of Network you are on, adjust the value of the 2 configuration parameters "**Network Interface Expected Link Speed**" and "**Network Interface Expected Duplex Mode**".

4- Deploy the new configuration and restart Cloudera Manager.